# hbase schema design - Template - Inheritance

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I have a requirement to display a parent child relationship. Other than the display parent/child would not have anything in common. The properties for each node will be inherited from Template. Only admin user can add/ edit Template node property's default values, which will get reflected to the user created nodes and they can override the template properties.

I had this structure in mySql. Now I am redesigning with Hbase (Huge Data). The project is at its early stage.

Please suggest me an perfect schema design for this. I am trying with Node/Edge design. Is there any other alternatives?

PS-I am new to Hbase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am following the below schema.

```
RowKey        | CF(a)                  
node-UUID     | t-node-UUID:"dummy"
              | p-node-UUID:"dummy"
              | c-node-UUID:"dummy"
              | i-node-UUID:"dummy"
```

and then in code, Separated key with prefix 't-' for template nodes, 'p-' for parent nodes, 'c-' for child nodes, 'i-' for instances.

Please answer if you have any other better idea.